# Internet explorer not working. giving cannot display web page error

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

So im using an old laptop to do a tech course. i have no prior experience but aim to switch jobs. i have just reformatted my hd with a downloaded copy of windows 7 ultimate. the internet explore will not go to most sites. it will go to google.com for instance and do a search but not go to any of the search returns. Gives "cannot display webpage" error. Ive looked for ms edge to download but can only find online versions which i can not get to on that pc. So i guess my need is a way to either fix IE so i can get at those or find a downloadable version of ms edge. Any direction is appreaciated

Comment: Microsoft Edge will install itself automatically on Windows 7 when it is fully updated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Internet Explorer is old and doesn't support websites that use
too-new features. Some alternatives are listed below.

- [Microsoft Edge supported Operating Systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-supported-operating-systems)
  lists
  [Microsoft Edge version 109](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=edge-stable-109)
  as the last version to support Windows 7.
- The Chromium-based Brave browser last version to support
  Windows 7 seems to be
  [Release v1.46.144 (Chromium 108.0.5359.128)](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/releases/tag/v1.46.144)
- [Firefox users on Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 moving to Extended Support Release](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-users-windows-7-8-and-81-moving-extended-support)
  lists Firefox version 115 as the last version to support
  Windows 7. See
  [Index of /pub/firefox/releases/](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/).

EDIT : Finally the problem wasn't with the browser
but with the installed root certificates.
Updating the
[Root Certificates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-urgent-trusted-root-updates-for-windows-root-certificate-program-in-windows-a4ac4d6c-7c62-3b6e-dfd2-377982bf3ea5)
fixed the problem.

Comment: hi again, i thought it was working properly but it seems i can only get to certain websites. like its going to .ca but not com

Comment: Sounds impossible. Try Firefox, as it's not at all based on Chromium.

Comment: Ok, so here is a better explanation of what it is doing. When i open edge; in the address bar it says edge://newtab. this will not load and gives me a page that says "your connection isnt private"   NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.     If in the address bar i type in "https://www.coursera.org" it will go to that site. same as "https://google.ca.   If i type in "https://www.office.com" it will go to the afore mentioned error page

Comment: This error occurs when the website's certificate validity cannot be verified. Try to update your [Root Certificates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-urgent-trusted-root-updates-for-windows-root-certificate-program-in-windows-a4ac4d6c-7c62-3b6e-dfd2-377982bf3ea5). This update is from 2015, but let's hope that it's enough.

Comment: Thank you. This update to root certificates seems to have done the trick.

Comment: If someone could explain the downvote ?